# In Cocoa, how do you change the line endings of a file to LF?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file-io

Do I have to read the files and iterate manually? I'd like to be able to change between LF and CRLF.

Comment: Can you explain, what you are trying to do? Do you want to change the files on disk or do you want to change line endings when you read the files only?

Comment: I'd prefer to change the files on disk, in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are more memory-efficient ways, but this might do the job for you:

```
NSStringEncoding usedEncoding;
NSMutableString *fileContents = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile usedEncoding:&usedEncoding error:nil];

// Normally you'd pass in an error and do the checking thing.

[fileContents replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\r\n" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [fileContents length])];
// The other direction: [fileContents replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@"\n" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [fileContents length])];

// Assumes you want to overwrite the file; again, normally you'd check for errors and such.
[fileContents writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:usedEncoding error:nil];
[fileContents release];
```

`pathToFile` is obviously the path to the file; substitute the `initWithContentsOfURL:...`/`writeToURL:...` versions if you prefer.

Comment: I just realized that this will cause issues if you read in a file that already uses CRLF line-endings; hopefully you already know this ahead of time/are detecting this. >_<

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "tr" command in the terminal.

Comment: No good way to do that in Cocoa without using NSTask to run a command?